# Method coming from nowhere?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in line: 87 in file jsp: /modules/login/pages/loginExtranet.jsp
The method setTest(boolean) in the type IfTag is not applicable for the arguments ()
84:                                 <span>*</span>
.
.
.
```

The code around is this:

```
<div>
    <label for="pass">
        Pass
    </label>
<input type="password" value="" id="pass" name="j_password"
    onfocus="this.value=''; this.onfocus=null;" />
    <span>*</span>
</div>
```

Where is coming from setTest? It feels to be an internal jsp method or something, I can't understand why am I getting this error...

Comment: That **JavaScript** code has nothing to do with the **Java** code generating the error. The error calls out that it's in an `IfTag`, so...look for the `<c:if ...` it relates to.

Comment: The point is that there isn't any `<c:if`, there actually was but it's commented.

Comment: We need much more context than the above. I suspect the `<c:if` isn't commented out correctly or similar, but if you don't show it... See: [mcve]

Comment: Actually I neither have more context. Finally I made it run changing the condition of the if, that was executing a method that had to be returning some undesired text and making it to execute arbitrary code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The use of a method into next if's condition was returning undesired text that abled the code to randomly crash.